# Is Archimate tool : Archi - Log4j Vulnerable

Tags: log4j, archimate

Whether Archimate tool : Archi is vulnerable to the log4j [CVE-2021-44228] impact? Is it using log4j first of all.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Archi Java Archimate Modeller does not use log4j and is therefore also not vulnerable to this issue.

See the answers to the question in the Forum:
https://github.com/archimatetool/archi/issues/795#issuecomment-996478526
https://forum.archimatetool.com/index.php?topic=1155.msg6168#msg6168

You can also search the code and will not find anything.
https://github.com/archimatetool/archi/search?q=log4j